# Edit form doesn't work php

Tags: php, mysql

Actualy was trying to solve the problem for 3 day and now have no idea what to do.
Edit form doesn't work. I have no error messages.

There is no save data file because i only output from database.
And **edit.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (empty($_POST['username'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваше имя";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваш email";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['task'])){
    $errors = "Впишите задание";
  }elseif (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $errors = "Вставьте картинку";
  }else{
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['username']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['email']));
     $task = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['task']));
        $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
          $_FILES['image']['name']);
        $target = "uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `username`='$username', `email`='$email',
         `task`='$task', `image`='$image'  WHERE `id`='$id'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
        $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        header('Location:' . $home_url);
     }
    }
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>задачник</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <h3>Внесение изменений в запись</h3>
     <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">На страницу 
администратора</a>
  </header>
  <br>
  <form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" class="input_form" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите Имя" 
class="username_input">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" 
class="email_input">
    <br>
    <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
  <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="Введите задание" 
class="task_input">
    <p>Сменить изображение</p>
  <input type="file" name="image" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg, 
image/gif">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="add_btn">Изменить 
запись</button>
</form>
```

I tried to `var_dump($_GET('edit'));` and i get the correct id of page that i want to edit, but after submit button i get redirected to index.php with no changes in db. `var_dump($_POST['submit']);` gives string(0), but save_task form from another folder for this proj works fine, giving string(0) after submit too.

Comment: Can you be more precise about your problem and reduce the given code to just that problem?

Comment: Try comment/disable the line `header('Location:' . $home_url);` So it's not redirected. Just to see if there any error throwed with the update query.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to injection attack since you're not escaping the `$id` parameter. Switch over to using [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). It's more robust and secure

Comment: @NicoHaase im sorry for that, but i thought that just showing edit.php file wouldn't give the full representation of the problem

Comment: @DharmaSaputra  now after clicking submit i have url like [test/edit.php]

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Update query in **edit.php** file is not correct.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `username`='$username', `email`='$email',`task`='$task',  WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Additional semicolon exists in update query before where clause.Remove it.

Comment: sorry for my innatatnion, i deleted some parts of code to watch how form would work without editing images and it gave me nothing, i updated sql with i$mages now

Comment: First of all, comment "header('Location:' . $home_url);" this line in "edit.php" file and see what error it throws.

Comment: after clicking submit i have url like [test/edit.php]

Comment: If the data is not getting saved then there must be an error message printed after you click submit.
Can you add following two lines at the top of edit.php file and submit form again.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

Comment: i get Notice: Undefined index: edit on line 14 `$id = $_GET['edit']; `

Comment: Check "action" attribute in form tag in edit.php file. (action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" ) .It should be (action="/<?PHP  echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>")

Comment: PHP_SELF doesn't append get parameters.

Comment: changing action attribute solved my problem, thanks alot for your help

Comment: Ok, I have posted this solution as new answer. Can you accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I think error is in `$image` value. debug yourself and find the error -

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo 'form submitted? -  okay <br/>';

  if (empty($_POST['username'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваше имя";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['email'])){
    $errors = "Впишите ваш email";
  }elseif (empty($_POST['task'])){
    $errors = "Впишите задание";
  }elseif (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $errors = "Вставьте картинку";
  }else{
     echo 'form validated? -  okay <br/>';
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['username']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['email']));
     $task = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
              trim($_POST['task']));
        $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
          $_FILES['image']['name']);

          //most probably error is here --- $_FILES['image']['name'] should gives you array!!! as you have used "multiple" in input

          var_dump($_FILES, $_FILES['image'], $_FILES['image']['name']); //die('debug--');

        $target = "uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $sql = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `username`='$username', `email`='$email',
         `task`='$task', `image`='$image'  WHERE `id`='$id'";

         echo $sql.'<br/>' ;  //copy this sql and run in phpmyadmin sql-console and check if there is any error
         die('checking sql statement');

        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target);
        $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        //header('Location:' . $home_url);
     }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: i get empty id in sql statement  `UPDATE `tasks` SET `username`='123qwe', `email`='123@gmail.rasr', `task`='123qwe', `image`='22111.jpg' WHERE `id`=''
checking sql statement`  but `var_dump($_GET['edit'])` gives the right id of data i want to edit

Comment: would you able to solve your problem now?? if not then update the question with appropriate problem

Answer (score 0):

Check "action" attribute in form tag in **edit.php** file. `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`  .It should be `action="/<?PHP echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"`.
PHP_SELF doesn't append get parameters.